# Double Grouping with PHP PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to fetch the record from mySQL database and group them. Lets take this table as an example:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
DATEADDED            DOCTYPE     SUBJECT    DETAILS
2018-03-03 9:54:54   DOCUMENT     Letter     Outgoing
2018-03-03 8:54:54   PARCEL       Mail       Incoming
2018-03-04 8:55:54   PARCEL       Mail       Incoming
2018-03-04 8:55:54   DOCUMENT     Mail       Outgoing
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I wanted to do is to group these data by date (without time) and then group by TYPE and COUNT it so it would look like this:

```
+++++++++++++++++++
DATE: April 3, 2018
      DOCUMENT - 1
      PARCEL -   1
 TOTAL-----------2

DATE: April 4, 2018
      DOCUMENT - 1
      PARCEL -   1
 TOTAL-----------2                     
++++++++++++++++++++
```

Have tried using the following code:

```
<?php 
foreach($page->query('SELECT id,dateAdded,COUNT(*) FROM seclogs GROUP BY DATE(dateAdded) desc') as $row) { ?><tr>
<td><?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['dateAdded'])); ?></td>
<td><?php 

$thisDate=date(strtotime($row['dateAdded']));
foreach($page->query("SELECT id,dateAdded,docType,COUNT(*) FROM seclogs WHERE DATE(dateAdded) LIKE '$thisDate' GROUP BY docType desc") as $row2) {

echo $row2['docType']."-".$row2['COUNT(*)']."<br/>"; } ?><br/><b><?php echo "Total: ".$row['COUNT(*)'].""; ?></b> </td> 
</tr><?php } ?>
```

but it only shows the following output:

```
+++++++++++++++++++
DATE: April 3, 2018


 TOTAL-----------2

DATE: April 4, 2018


 TOTAL-----------2                     
++++++++++++++++++++
```

I have been working and searching this issue everywhere but can't find any answer. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The exact output you want is really a presentation thing, and can be handled in your PHP code fairly easily.  As for the query, the following is what I would use for the raw data you will need:

```
SELECT
    DATE(dateAdded) AS dateAdded,
    docType,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM seclogs
GROUP BY
    DATE(dateAdded),
    docType
ORDER BY
    DATE(dateAdded),
    docType;
```

Of course, this won't give your desired output, at least not exactly.  What you need to do now is to use a loop which only prints the date at the start of each date/type group.